# This keyword points to global object in class method?

Tags: class, methods, this

I'm building a calculator using a class. Now I'm testing to see when i hit a number button that it will be displayed. It doesn't there is an error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined.
Now when I remove the this keyword in the updateDisplay method everything works fine? As if the this keyword points to the global object? What is happening here?

```
const numberButtons =  document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');        
const operationButtons =  document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous- 
operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current- 
operand]');



class Calculator {

contructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {      

     this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
     this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
     this.clear();                                                     
}

clear() {
    this.currentOperand = '';
    this.previousOperand = '';
    this.operation = undefined;
}

delete(){

}

appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = number;
}

chooseOperation(operation) {

}

compute() {

}

updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
    /* the code above throws an error, below works fine, so without the 
       this keyword? */
    currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;

}
}


const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, 
currentOperandTextElement);

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)                 

    calculator.updateDisplay();
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misspelled constructor.